# Duplicate results found when getting images from a path with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

there is a little problem that happens when i try to get the images from a path on a live server
(My website) and honestly i don't know why....
i've tried to fix that a thousand times but i'm not able to fix it

This is the code that i have (The function it's called every time when the page loads):

```
<body onload="loadusercont()">
```

this is the js/jquery (i only get the first image duplicate):

```
var img_index = 1;
function loadusercont(){
   var folder = "/example/folder/";

$.ajax({
url : folder,
success: function (data) {
    $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
        if ( val.match(/\.(jpeg|png)$/) ){  
        var img = $('<img />').attr({
        'id': 'Image'+img_index,
        'src': folder + val,
        'alt': val,
        'title': val,
        'class': 'img',

        }).appendTo('#container');
        img_index++;
        }

    });

}});
}
```

and here it's the html code too:

```
<div id="galleria" class="gallery-section">
  <div class="inner-width">
    <h1>My Gallery (user)</h1>
    <div class="border"></div>
    <div id="gallery" class="gallery">

    <div id="container">

    </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the result should be that every time the pages loads/refresh get the images from that path and dynamically puts the images in to img tag with a different id, but when that happens the images get duplicated... HOW TO FIX THIS? 
[RESULT CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do8aq.jpg)

edit

with this code i get all but also duplicate images

```
$.ajax({
url : folder,
success: function (data) {
    $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
        if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
            $("body").append( "<img src='"+ folder + val +"'>" );
        } 
    });
}
```

});

Comment: please add an example of the response from the server

Comment: Sounds like you have duplicate `href` values in `<a>` in response html

Comment: i've put a image of the result now

Comment: I tried your code and I did not have issue of duplicate images. However some random images were not listed.  I had to modify this a bit  -  if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { - to this - if ( val.match(/\.(png|jpg|jpeg)$/) ){  . And then all images were listed.  Hope this helps.